# Show that $f(\rho)=0$ for any modular form of weight $k$ if $\rho=e^{\frac{2\pi i}{3}}$ and $3\nmid k$.

Tags: complex-analysis, representation-theory, analytic-number-theory, modular-forms, automorphic-forms

In Exercise 1.3.3 from *Automorphic Forms and Representations*, Daniel Bump gives the hint as follows:

> Observe that $\gamma(\rho)=\rho$ where $\gamma= \begin{pmatrix} 1&1\\
>  -1& \\ \end{pmatrix}$, and apply $$f\left(\frac{az+b}{cz+d}\right)=(cz+d)^kf(z)\ \ \text{for}\ \
>  \begin{pmatrix} a&b\\ c&d\\
>  \end{pmatrix}\in\mathrm{SL}(2,\mathbb{Z}).$$

However, I feel confused about the hint and wonder how to prove it.

1. For $\rho=e^{\frac{2\pi i}{3}}$ a complex number and $\gamma$ a
   matrix, how to understand the equation $\gamma(\rho)=\rho$ ?
2. Having applied the formula, I get
   $$f\left(\frac{z+1}{-z}\right)=(-z)^kf(z).$$ For
   $z=\rho=e^{\frac{2\pi i}{3}}$, it follows that
   $$f\left(-1-e^{-\frac{2\pi i}{3}}\right)=(-1)^ke^{\frac{2k\pi
   i}{3}}f\left(e^{\frac{2\pi i}{3}}\right).$$ How to demonstrate that
   $f(\rho)=0$?

Comment: SL(2,Z) acts on the upper-half plane, so (1) means $\rho$ is a fixed point of this transformation.  (Think rotation about $\rho$.)

Comment: Thanks, I got it @Kimball. Since
$$\gamma(\rho)=\frac{e^{\frac{2\pi i}{3}}+1}{-e^{\frac{2\pi i}{3}}+0}=e^{\frac{2\pi i}{3}}$$
where $\gamma=\begin{pmatrix}
1&1\\
-1& \\
\end{pmatrix}$, we have $\gamma(\rho)=\rho$. Could you illuminate further proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple proof:

By definition, we have

$$
f(\rho)=f(\gamma(\rho))=(-\rho)^kf(\rho).
$$

Because $k$ is automatically even, we have

$$
(1-\rho^k)f(\rho)=0
$$

Since $\rho^k\ne1$ if and only if $3\nmid k$, we conclude that $f(\rho)=0$ in this case.

My original proof:

Let $\nu_p(f)$ denote the unique integer such that $f(z)(z-p)^{-\nu_p(f)}$ is analytic and nonzero at $z=p$, so when $f$ is a modular form of weight $k$ on $SL(2,\mathbb Z)$, there is

$$
\frac12\nu_i(f)+\frac13\nu_\rho(f)+\nu_\infty(f)+\sum_{\substack{p\in\mathcal F\\p\ne i,\rho}}\nu_p(f)={k\over12}.
$$

Consequently, multiplying both sides by $12$ gives ($k$ is assumed to be even)

$$
4\nu_\rho(f)\equiv k-6\nu_i(f)\pmod{12}
$$

Suppose $v_\rho(f)=0$. Then the right hand side will be $\equiv0\pmod3$, so

$$
k\equiv6\nu_i(f)\equiv0\pmod3.
$$

Therefore, we proved the contrapositive: If $f(\rho)\ne0$, then $3|k$.

Comment: Thanks! I have two questions about your answer. 1. How to conclude the equation you mention as follows? $$
\frac12\nu_i(f)+\frac13\nu_\rho(f)+\nu_\infty(f)+\sum_{\substack{p\in\mathcal F\\p\ne i,\rho}}\nu_p(f)={k\over12}.
$$ Is it from a certain theorem? 2. Where do you apply the fact $\gamma(\rho)=\rho$? I hope to find a method by using the hint Daniel Bump gives.

Comment: This equation can be proved by applying argument principle to the boundary of the fundamental domain. See §6.3 of Apostol's _Modular Functions and Dirichlet Series in Number Theory_ for details.

Comment: I just updated the answer to include the simple proof using the $\gamma(\rho)=\rho$