# A First Course in Modular Forms Ex. 1.1.8

Tags: modular-forms

Question:

> Exercise 1.1.8 Recall that $\mu_3$ denotes the complex cube root of unity $e^{2\pi i/3}$. Show that
> $$\begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1\\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix} \mu_3 = \mu_3 +1$$ and by periodicity
> $$g_2(\begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1\\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix} \mu_3) = g_2(\mu_3).$$ Show that by modularity also
> $$g_2(\begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1\\ 1 & 0\end{pmatrix} \mu_3) = \mu_3^4 g_2(\mu_3)$$ and therefore $g_2(\mu_3)=0$. Conclude that $g_3(\mu_3) \neq 0$ and $j(\mu_3) =0$. Argue similarly to show that $g_3(i) =0$, $g_2(i) \neq 0$ and $j(i) = 1728$.

My attempt: I am able to show that $g_2(\mu_3) =0$ and $g_3(i) =0$. However, is there any way I can show that $g_3(\mu_3) \neq 0$ and $g_2(i) \neq 0$ without the use of the valence formula? Any hints are appreciated.

Source: [Diamond and Shurman's A Fist Course in Modular Forms](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-0-387-27226-9)

Comment: I think the book is using the later result that $\Delta$ only has a zero at $\infty$. $(1.1.8)$ is used as an excuse to skip some detail on page $7$, where they discuss poles and zeros of the $j$-function.

Comment: I see, thank you

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4777820/show-that-f-rho-0-for-any-modular-form-of-weight-k-if-rho-e-frac2-pi/4777997#4777997